# Magento mage-translation-storage is empty

Tags: javascript, magento2

I am currently working on a Magento 2.3.4 webshop and my Javascript translations aren't working. When looking at the "Application" tab in the developer tools I noticed that the "mage-translation-storage" entry in local storage was empty.

I checked some other Magento sites and saw the following code in the body of the document:

```
<script>
    require.config({
        deps: [
            'jquery',
            'mage/translate',
            'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
        ],
        callback: function ($) {
            'use strict';

            var dependencies = [],
                versionObj;

            $.initNamespaceStorage('mage-translation-storage');
            $.initNamespaceStorage('mage-translation-file-version');
            versionObj = $.localStorage.get('mage-translation-file-version');


            if (versionObj.version !== '3ad475b1a657146524fbb27435adb14607dee032') {
                dependencies.push(
                    'text!js-translation.json'
                );

            }

            require.config({
                deps: dependencies,
                callback: function (string) {
                    if (typeof string === 'string') {
                        $.mage.translate.add(JSON.parse(string));
                        $.localStorage.set('mage-translation-storage', string);
                        $.localStorage.set(
                            'mage-translation-file-version',
                            {
                                version: '3ad475b1a657146524fbb27435adb14607dee032'
                            }
                        );
                    } else {
                        $.mage.translate.add($.localStorage.get('mage-translation-storage'));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

This code is being printed in `Magento_Translation/view/base/templates/translate.php`. This code is not present in the body of the webshop I'm currently working on and I can't figure out why. I'm guessing this is the reason why the "mage-translation-storage" entry in local storage is empty.

I tried disabling my custom theme and modules, I cleared the cache multiple times but that piece of code just doesn't appear in the body of the document.

Has someone else ever encountered this problem before? Is this a Magento bug or just me being a plonker?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?